# Problem getting value from a proxies object in Symfony 5 with easy admin 3

Tags: symfony5, proxies, easyadmin3

I have a ManyToMany relation. It return a collection type which I have in $collectionProductAutoclave. When I dump it, I get my objects, so no problem. However, some of them are proxies, and I can't manage to get value from it, only true boolean.
I want to compare id from this object with another.
here the dump of my var:

dump($collectionProductAutoclave);

```
^ array:2 [▼
  0 => Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Product {#1423 ▼
    +__isInitialized__: true
    -id: 1
    -titre: "dfg"
    -diametreTube: "45"
    -workCharge: 4
    -tension: 45
    -montageCharge: 1
    -stockFuseaux: false
    -type: "dfg"
    -commandes: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#1547 ▶}
    -materiau: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Materiau {#1565 ▶}
    -papier: 789
    -diametreFuseaux: 45
    -Intensity: 456
    -HauteurMax: "465"
    -HauteurStandard: "465"
    -autoclaves: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#1564 ▶}
     …2
  }
  1 => App\Entity\Product {#1318 ▼
    -id: 2
    -titre: "dsfgzerezer"
    -diametreTube: "45"
    -workCharge: 1
    -tension: 456
    -montageCharge: 2
    -stockFuseaux: false
    -type: "zer"
    -commandes: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#1455 ▶}
    -materiau: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Materiau {#1565 ▶ …2}
    -papier: 45
    -diametreFuseaux: 21
    -Intensity: 987
    -HauteurMax: "123"
    -HauteurStandard: "123"
    -autoclaves: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#1566 ▶}
  }
]
```

dump($collectionProductAutoclave->getValues());

```
^ array:2 [▼
  0 => true
  1 => App\Entity\Product {#1318 ▶}
]
```

I only saw very old answer to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out ! When testing my values, i got true bool on proxies objects if i used a while loop. But using a foreach $vars as var loop prevented doctrine to make proxies and made me able to get values from this.